# recommend folder structure for liferay maven project using liferay developer studio

Tags: maven, liferay

We just started with a liferay extranet project. We want it to be as much mavenized as possible. So far I [read](http://www.liferay.com/de/web/mika.koivisto/blog/-/blogs/getting-started-with-liferay-maven-sdk) how to get it working with `Maven` and have a working setup. But I have some questions regarding the folder structure:

- Do I need an (unpacked) sdk at all?
- How should the folder structure look like (in future there will be many portlets, themes, exts... plugins)?

at the moment my structure looks like this:

```
liferay-portal-6.1.20-ee-ga2 (liferay tomcat bundle)
 |-deploy
 |-tomcat-7.0.27
 |...
project-folder
 |-pom.xml (parent pom)
 |-sample-portlet (created with archetype:generate)
```

Is this ok? or it is probably better to create subfolders for each plugin type? does this interfere with the archetype and the automated connection between parent-pom and modules?

Does the mavenization changes something with workflow of liferay developer studio? This will be the ide of choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your questions

1. You don't need `plugins-sdk` at all!
2. I advice you to go for a multi module maven project, and I already see you using it.

   Obviously when you go for a multi-module project you have the sub-folders created and each module corresponds to a separate `archetype` and of course, it depends on what type of project you create.

Here is the sample liferay-maven project structure I had.

[image]

Comment: so you suggest not to create a subfolder for each kind of plugin/archetype, but to have all plugins in one folder? i thought this could become messy if there are many plugins?!

Comment: @dermoritz I didn't suggest that. 
Multi module result in a folder or sub-folder. But, subfolders give a good hierarchical structure.
What I meant was each module corresponds to a subfolder and a module can be a `liferay-plugin` archetype (`lead-portlet`, `mbcp-hook` etc.) or can be any other archetype (`mbcp-beans`) as shown in the screenshot.

Comment: in your example all plugins are on the same folder - all portlets (3), themes, hooks and so on. my question was is it good idea to create a folder for each archtype and to put all modules of this archetype in this dedicated folder. but in this case i probably have to modify the pom files -the part pointing from/to modules/parents?